# Solving a system of separable ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I am attempting to solve the system of first-order ODE's:

$$ \frac{dy_1(x)}{dx} = g(y_1)\frac{y_2(x)}{\int_{a}^b y_2(z) dz} $$
$$ \frac{dy_2(x)}{dx} = \frac{y_2(x)}{f(y_1(x),x)} \frac{\partial f(y_1(x),x)}{\partial x} $$

with boundary conditions $y_1(a) = c$, $y_1(b) = d$ for constants $a,b,c,d$.

My problem is conceptual, and very likely silly: I'm not sure whether I can break apart this problem apart in order to solve it. I would like to exploit separability to obtain a general solution for the second equation:

$$ y_2(x) = e^N f(y_1(x),x) $$

with N a constant, and use this to reduce the first equation to

$$ \frac{dy_1(x)}{dx} = g(y_1)\frac{f(y_1(x),x)}{\int_{a}^b f(y_1(z),z) dz} $$

which I would then solve numerically, presumably by treating the integral as a constant to be determined. I'm not seeing the problem with this approach, but on the other hand it strikes me as "too good to be true." My questions:

1. Am I mistaken in thinking that $ y_2(x) = e^N f(y_1(x),x) $ is in fact the general solution for $y_2$, irrespective of the dependence of $y_1$ on $y_2$?
2. When numerically solving a differential equation (say IVP) of the form $y_1'(x) = h\left(y_1,x,\int_{a}^b f(y_1(z),z) dz\right)$ with $a,b$ constant, is it problematic to treat the integral as a constant $A$, use an initial guess for $A$ + e.g Euler's method to solve for $y_1$, and then iterating until the guess and actual value of $A$ converge?

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your first equation $f$ takes in one input, but in your second equation $f$ takes in two inputs. Should these be two different functions? Or is there a typo? And is $\frac{\delta}{\delta x}$ supposed to be $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$?

Comment: Note also that your second equation can be written as $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(y_2)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ln(f(y_1,x))$.

Comment: You are correct - it was a typo, they are two different functions. I’ve edited the question to fix this. And yes the deltas were sloppy short-hand partials, which I’ve also edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Your system does not define $y_2(x)$ uniquely. If $(y_1(x), y_2(x))$ is a solution then also $(y_1(x), Cy_2(x))$ where $C \neq 0$ is a constant also is a solution.

Thus you may impose an extra condition on $y_2(x)$, the simplest to me is
$$
\int_a^b y_2(x) dx = 1.
$$
After that the system reduces to
$$
y_1'(x) = g(y_1(x)) y_2(x)\\
y_2'(x) = y_2(x) F(x, y_1(x))
$$
with conditions $y_1(a) = c, y_1(b) = d, \int_a^b y_2(x) dx = 1$.
Here I've denoted $F(x, y) = \frac{f_x(y, x)}{f(y, x)}$.

Having a system of two first-order ODE's with three conditions makes me think that the **problem does not have a solution in general** (but may have for some particular values of $c$ or $d$, like an eigenproblem).

The general solution to the second equation is
$$
y_2(x) = C_1 \exp\left(\int_a^x F(s, y_1(s)) ds\right)
$$
with $C_1$ determined by $\int_a^b y_2(x) dx = 1$ condition. Practically it is easier to put $y_2(a) = C_1 = 1$ and normalize $y_2(x)$ after integration.

Summarizing, the following algorithm may solve the problem:

1. Take some initial $y_1(x)$, e.g. linear approximation $y_1(x) = c + \frac{x-a}{b-a} (d - c)$.
2. Having $y_1(x)$ compute the ${\tilde y}_2(x)$ from the following Cauchy problem
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   \tilde y_2'(x) = \tilde y_2(x) F(x, y_1(x)), &\quad x \in [a, b]\\
   I'(x) = \tilde y_2(x), &\quad x \in [a, b]\\
   \tilde y_2(a) = 1\\
   I(a) = 0
   \end{cases}
   $$
   Here $I(x) = \int_a^x y_2(s) ds$, so $I(b) = \int_a^b y_2(x) dx$.
3. Compute $y_2(x)$ by $$y_2(x) = \frac{\tilde y_2(x)}{I(b)}.$$
4. Plug obtained $y_2(x)$ into the first equation and solve the new Cauchy problem
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   \tilde y_1'(x) = g(\tilde y_1(x)) y_2(x)\\
   \tilde y_1(a) = c\\
   \end{cases}
   $$
5. Now, for sure, $\tilde y_1(b) \neq d$, so we need to correct $y_1(x)$ and start from the item 2. And this is quite tricky. As I said, the problem almost certainly won't have a solution. If it was a boundary problem with three conditions and the functions we might have use the residual $\delta = d - \tilde y_1(b)$ to correct some free parameter (see [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method)), but there is no such parameter in this problem, at least as it was stated. You may try combining new approximation $y_1(x)$ as
   $$y_1(x) := (1-\omega) y_1(x) + \omega \left[\tilde y_1(x) + \frac{x-a}{b-a}\delta\right]$$
   and try to deduce how $\delta$ behaves in iterations depending on different $\omega$ values. The extra term in brackets is needed to correct the right boundary conditions in new $y_1(x)$ before restarting from item 2.